# xslt Removing particular namespace from root only

Tags: xslt

I want to remove namespace (xmlns="http://www.cric.com") in the root element and also the comments.
Input xml looks like this

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <AM xmlns="http://www.cric.com" name="Asmkl">
                <!-- Sets a new value to the existing parameter -->
<set>
                    <Payload>
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
                            <soapenv:Header />
                            <soapenv:Body>
                                <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
                                    <!--Optional:-->
                                    <web:CountryName>india</web:CountryName>
                                </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
                            </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                    </Payload>
                    <Verb>POST</Verb>
                </Set>
            </AM>
```

I have tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.cric.com']"> 
    <xsl:choose> 
       <xsl:when test="local-name(.)='root'"> 
        <xsl:element name="root"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
        </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:when>  
      <!-- Copy other elemnts -->  
      <xsl:otherwise> 
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
        </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:template>  
  <!-- Copy the rest -->  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet removes from root but adding the namespace in soapenv:Envelope tag.

Desired output is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <AM name="Asmkl">
              <Set>
                    <Payload>
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
                            <soapenv:Header />
                            <soapenv:Body>
                                <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
                                    <web:CountryName>india</web:CountryName>
                                </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
                            </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>
                    </Payload>
                    <Verb>POST</Verb>
                </Set>
            </AM>
```

but I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><AM name="Asmkl">

    <!-- Sets a new value to the existing parameter -->
    <Set>
       <Payload>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns="http://www.cric.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:CountryName>india</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
      </Payload>
      <Verb>POST</Verb>
    </Set>
</AM>
```

Kindly suggest. XSLT processor is 1.0

Comment: Please show us the output you want to create for the input sample you have posted and also the output you get currently with your posted code. Also explain if you use an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor.

Comment: And why do you have the check `<xsl:when test="local-name(.)='root'">` although the XML sample has no element named `root`?

Comment: And your input sample has a closing `</Set>` without an opening `<Set>`.

Comment: @Martin I have updated the question and regarding "root" in style sheet is just a dummy root. The input xml root name can be anything like now it is AM but it can change. So can't relay  on root name. just have to remove namespace from root element and comments from xml. rest all should remain same as input xml.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- move elements in the default namespace into no namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.cric.com']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

<!-- "copy" all other elements, without copying the default namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example (after correcting `<set>` to `<Set>`!), the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AM name="Asmkl">
   <Set>
      <Payload>
         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
               <web:GetCitiesByCountry xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
                  <web:CountryName/>
               </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
            </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
      </Payload>
      <Verb/>
   </Set>
</AM>
```

---

Note:

> I want to remove namespace (xmlns="http://www.cric.com") in the root
>   element

I am not sure if you realize that the default namespace declared in the root element:

```
<AM xmlns="http://www.cric.com" name="Asmkl">
```

is also inherited by the `Set` and `Payload` elements.

Comment: it is removing the namespace from root but adding unnecessary namespaces in other tag like  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
               <web:GetCitiesByCountry xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><!--Optional:--><web:CountryName>india</web:CountryName>
               </web:GetCitiesByCountry>

Comment: @Ashes These namespace declarations are not "unnecessary". On the contrary: they are **required**: without them, the result will not be a well-formed XML document (you cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace). Note also that the same namespace declarations appear - quite correctly -  in your desired output.

Comment: namespace "xmlns:web ="http://www.webserviceX.NET" should be in <soapenv:Envelope> not in <web:GetCitiesByCountry>.

Comment: @Ashes What difference does it make?

Comment: Has to pass with same input as it is coming except the removal of root namespace and comments. One more question I have if XSLT processor is 1.0 how to achieve this.

Comment: The XSLT processor is 1.0.

Comment: @Ashes: you really shouldn't care about the location of the declarations of the namespace **declarations**, you should only care about whether any element is in a certain namespace or not, the so-called **qualified name**. The processor is **required** to move the namespace _declarations_ around in such a way that your qualified names (or qname for short) are still valid. This is called the **namespace fixup process**. You seem to be mixing the physical representation with the semantic representation.

Comment: @Ashes, also, except perhaps for some extremely old processors from before the namespace era, all XML processors I have seen will correctly interpret namespaces. Which means that any tool you are using, provided it understands XML, will interpret your data correctly.

Comment: PS: Michael, I believe it is generally saver to use `name="{local-name()}"`, as if a name is prefixed, the `xsl:element` instruction will fail.

Comment: @Abel I have hesitated about that, but you're right - it's safer with `local-name()`. -- As an aside: in my relatively short time here I have seen quite a few requests to produce a specific *lexical* result, due to the receiving application being unable to parse a semantically identical XML.

Comment: That's troublesome, depending to what level that is. In XSLT, you can force a namespace to appear on a certain element (even if not used there yet). But you cannot define the order, nor can you define the order of attributes. If such applications exist and claim they are XML conformant, then it certainly limits and/or confuse users.

Comment: @Abel There's a *lot* of troublesome things you encounter here on SO... ;-).